# facebook picture url convert to base 64

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, react-native

I'm trying to convert the picture url that I get from facebook graph api to base64 to store and use it in react native. is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using the `node-base64-image` module.  Assuming you have a remote URL and want to produce a base64 string:

```
const base64 = require('node-base64-image');

let url = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/45170/kittens-cat-cat-puppy-rush-45170.jpeg'
let options = { string: true }

base64.encode(url, options, (err, result) => console.log(result));
```

Full documentation on this module is here: https://github.com/riyadhalnur/node-base64-image/blob/HEAD/docs/docs.md